# Rich text editor for AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ckeditor

Is there any rich text editor available that can generate "AS3 Compatible" codes?
I want to add this to the web admin, where user can set the font size and color of the text and it should generate as3 compatible code like:

```
<p><font size="12" color="#000000">Welcome to</font> <font size="30" color="#ffffff">My Website</font></p>
```

I used the CKEditor, but it generates like this:

```
<p><span style="font-size:12px; color:#000000">Welcome to</span></p>
```

I am assigning this value in my textfield with txt.htmlText.

If there is not any such text editor available, is there any way to render the above "span style" in the as3 textfield?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you say that you've been using CKEditor, it seems that you haven't configured it correctly.
Check this sample: http://nightly.ckeditor.com/latest/ckeditor/_samples/output_for_flash.html

Comment: You are right. I got the CKEditor setting to get the output for flash. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As nowadays CSS is common practice, I guess it'll be hard to find an editor that will spit old style html. Flash only supports a handful of html tags. So you might want to use the CKEditor output, strip the style part, scour it for tags that flash would support and inject those back into the html.

[edit] I found something related [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=221626)